# excercise about Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Analysis insituttet Super Observer has analyzed how voters change party within one year. For simplicity, we assume that there are only three parties $V, S$ and $D$ of the voter walks looks like this:

$V: 30$% of those who would vote for $V$ last year, has switched to $D$, the rest will continue to vote for $V$.

$D: 30$% of those who would vote for $D$ last year, has switched to $V$; $30$% of those who would vote for $D$ last year, has switched to $S$, the rest will continue to vote for $D$.

$S: 30$% of those who would vote for $S$ last year, has switched to $D$, the rest will continue to vote for $S$.

If $v, d$ and $s$ is the proportion of voters who would vote for $V, D$ and S last year, then the corresponding shares $v_1, d_1$ and $s_1$ now given by

$$(v_1;d_1;s_1)=A^*(v;d;s),$$

where

$$ A= \pmatrix{0.7 & 0.3 & 0 \\ 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\ 0& 0.3 & 0.7}$$

(The matrix $A$ is called the transition matrix)

$b)$ Is there an equilibrium state $(v^*;d^*;s^*)$ then $(v^*;d^*;s^*) = A^* (v^*;d^*;s^*)$?

What does it mean saying "is there an equilibrium"??

Comment: -1, you haven't demonstrated anything to show what you have tried or what part you are getting stuck with.  Just a dump of a rather tedious looking question

Comment: Indeed. Do you know what a cofactor is? what an adjoint matrix is? how to invert a matrix? This could be a good question, if you would tell us why you are interested in this question, and what you know about it, and how far you can get, and where you get stuck. As is, it's substandard, and I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's true, I have already done the first part, the inverse and all this things, is just that I don't understand the last question. Now I edited

Comment: Thanks for the change, I have changed my vote to +1.  Don't let this experience discourage you from using Math.SE, just remember we like helping with maths but we are not a homework machine and so we upvote and downvote based on demonstrable research effort.

Answer (score 1):

For the new edited question, what you are looking for is a solution for the equation $Ax = x$.  This is called an equilibrium position because the percentage of voters doesn't change even after the transition.  To see if an equilibrium position exists, it is simply a matter of checking if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Compute the determinant $|A - I|$ and see if it is $0$ or not.

Comment: It's guaranteed that $1$ is an eigenvalue, since the matrix is stochastic. Indeed, this particular matrix is doubly-stochastic, which makes finding an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$ very simple.

Comment: Ah, I have to look into that to see what that means, I did think all the sums being equal to $1$ would imply some sort of additional structure but I wasn't sure what.  Thanks :)